# oracle to_date returns some error in custom query

Tags: sql, oracle

**Oracle DB**

```
START_DATE          |END_DATE           
--------------------|-------------------
2016-02-01 00:00:00 |2016-02-29 23:55:00
2016-02-01 00:00:00 |2016-02-29 23:55:00
2016-02-01 00:00:00 |2016-02-29 23:55:00
2016-02-01 00:00:00 |2016-02-29 23:55:00
2016-02-01 00:00:00 |2016-02-29 23:55:00
```

**Query**

```
`select * from  VM_REPORT_TEMP_US where to_date(START_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= '2016-02-01 00:00:00' AND to_date(END_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') <= '2016-`02-24 24:59:00'`
```

Im trying to run this query but im getting some error. Can some one know where im going in this query ?

Im getting the below error

> SQL Error [1861] [22008]: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
>
> java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do **NOT** use `to_date()` with a `DATE` column. That first converts the `date` value into a `varchar` value just to convert that back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

`to_date()` expects a `varchar` value, so Oracle first converts the `DATE` value into a `varchar` value using the current NLS settings. Then it tries to convert that `varchar` back into a date, using the format mask you supplied which most probably doesn't match the default NLS format you have and therefor you get an error.

You should also use proper date values in the condition rather then strings that are (again) implicitly converted to a `DATE` based on the current NLS settings:

```
select * 
from VM_REPORT_TEMP_US 
where START_DATE >= timestamp '2016-02-01 00:00:00' 
  AND END_DATE <= timestamp '2016-02-24 23:59:00'
```

Note that the hour `24` is invalid in an ISO timestamp literal.

If you want to provide the date/timestamp value in a format other then the ISO format, you need to use `to_date()` for those:

```
select * 
from VM_REPORT_TEMP_US 
where START_DATE >= to_date('01.02.2016 00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
  AND END_DATE <= to_date('24.02.2016 23:59:59', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: it retruns some error like this `SQL Error [933] [42000]: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

  java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Comment: Good explanation on what is happening in OP's query. I was just about to add that to my answer when you posted yours :-)

Comment: And I didn't spot the 24 hour either.

Answer (score 2):

`start_date` and `end_date` are dates already, so you don't have to convert them to date. Convert the strings instead or even better use datetime literals.

```
select * 
from  VM_REPORT_TEMP_US 
where START_DATE >= timestamp '2016-02-01 00:00:00' 
and END_DATE <= timestamp '2016-02-24 00:59:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit different from both the above answers, but this is what I would use to avoid confusion between `YYYY-MM-DD` and `YYYY-DD-MM`.

```
select * from  VM_REPORT_TEMP_US 
where 
START_DATE >= to_date('2016-02-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
AND 
END_DATE   <= to_date('2016-02-24 00:59:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```